# How to change all title attribute's value in Title Case in sublime text

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext3

I have 500  HTML files in my project where casing  and quotes (`"` or  `'`) in `<title>` attribute vary over all pages, see few examples below

```
<button title="Next" id="next"> Next</button>
<button title="next"> Next </buton>
<button title=""please go back">Check</button>
```

I want to change all title attributes in **Title Case**

```
<button title="Next" id="next"> Next</button>
<button title="Next"> Next </buton>
<button title="Please Go Back">Check</button>#
```

I have tried to find and replace - Regular Expression and Case sensitive button enabled

> **Find What:** `title=(".*")\s`
>   **Replace With:** `title="\u$"`

But didn't get success.Please tell me what I am doing wrong?

UPDATED : also want to remove extra `' "` see #

Comment: Is the issue that too much is getting replaced with what you have tried? If so, try using `[code]title=(".*?")\s[/code]` (note the `?` after `.*`) This makes the `.*` 'lazy', meaning it will match as little as possible until the next `[\code]`.

Comment: @jerry Thanks for quick reply even I was editing the format. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To further my comment, first it's the issue of `.*` being 'greedy' instead of 'lazy', meaning it is matching as much as possible (i.e. `Next"> Next</button><button title="Next` in your example).

The quick fix is using a 'lazy' `.*` instead, aka `.*?` (I added a `?` to indicate possible presence of space because there's none in your examples):

```
title=(".*?")\s?
```

To improve performance, you would use a negated class:

```
title=("[^"]+")\s?
```

Where `[^"]+` matches any character except `"`.

And to cope with the different quotes, you can use:

```
title=("[^"]+"|'[^']+')\s?
```

Which basically means either `"[^"]+"` or `'[^']+'` for the part within the parentheses.

---

For the replace and consecutive quotes issue:

```
title=(?:"+([^"]+)"+|'+([^']+)'+)\s?
```

Replace with:

```
title="\u$1$2"
```

The only thing is that the last line will be `<button title="Please go back">Check</button>`, if that's not an issue...

EDIT: `\G` actually works. Use a second replace:

```
(?:(?<=title=")|(?<!^)\G)[^\s"]+\s?
```

Replace with:

```
\u$0
```

Comment: @diEcho I like starting from what's wrong and fixing little by little :) Unless the regex needs a complete rework, you'd get a long long explanation xD Thanks!

Comment: what about this `title=""please go back"`

Comment: but it doesn't case the title . I was asking for sublime IDE help

Comment: can you show me one example for which this one is justfied. i didnt get this `title=("[^"]+")\s?` specially that + (1 or more)

Comment: @diEcho I have added a different regex (see the part after the separator), and added a second replace to fix the first letter uppercase for each word in the title.

Comment: @jerry thank you for that. but for the comment section, I just want to summarize how this one will helps us in which condition?

Comment: @diEcho `title=("[^"]+")\s?` works only if you have one word in the title and it's surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: Thanks dude. additionaly have to on case sensitive button with above regex

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=title=('|")).+?(?=('|"))
```

this should give you matches `Next` `next` `please go back` that you can use.

you can use the index of the match to find your match in the Original string if you want to upper your lowers..

or use  `title=('|").+?(\1)` to find any title attributes in your tekst including the quotation marks

Comment: didn't know ST3 support look ahead/ look behind ? :)

Comment: `('|")(\1)` will find any "" or ''

Comment: but it doesnt help. my issue is not regex exactly

Comment: `title=('|")(.+?)(\1)` and use `\u$2` to upper what is found in `(.+?)`, would that do the trick ?